# What does fun keyword do in Coq?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, coq, dependent-type

I am struggling to understand the meaning of keyword 'fun' in Coq.

There are types all and function forallb:

```
Inductive all (X : Type) (P : X -> Prop) : list X -> Prop :=
  | all_nil : all X P []
  | all_cons : forall (x:X) (l: list X) , P x -> all X P l -> all X P (x::l).

Fixpoint forallb {X : Type} (test : X -> bool) (l : list X) : bool :=
 match l with
| [] => true
| x :: l' => andb (test x) (forallb test l')
end.
```

And theorem:

```
Theorem all_spec: forall (X:Type) (test : X -> bool) (l: list X),
    forallb test l = true <-> all X (fun x => test x = true) l.
```

I understand the left part but confused on what fun is doing on the right side of the <->.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't it simply like a *lambda*, i.e., isn't here `fun x => ...` simply like `\x -> ...` in Haskell?

There is another interesting peculiarity of that `fun ...` in your code. The type of the result of that function in your code must be *proposition* (`Prop`), not *boolean*. The expression `test x = true` must be of that type, so we conclude that `=` in coq denotes propositions about equality, not the boolean binary operation (which is known as `==` in Haskell; we don't see this from your example, but perhaps coq's notation is similar).

So, although the idea of this `fun ...` is just a *lambda*, it is a bit unusual from Haskell's point of view, because here it introduces a function operating on type-level (the result type is `Prop`), not value-level (only the latter must be possible--or at least the usual usage--for `\ x-> ...` in Haskell). coq's `Prop` is on the same level as `*` in Haskell, isn't it?

And `all X P` in this code is like a type constructor (well, a parameterized family of type constructors) in Haskell, but a dependent one, of type `[X] -> *` (in Haskell's notation). `all_nil` and `all_cons` are like data constructors for this new type.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I don't think it is a great idea to explain things in terms of Haskell.

Comment: @Ptival I agree with your remark generally, of course. But I couldn't do better because I'm used to Haskell, but interested in understanding coq deeply, so I need to translate the basic notions between the two programming systems. After that I have a feeling of a more clear picture.